# Separating date and month from the given date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've created a text-box where I'm binding date and year. This is how I've done:

```
jQuery("#year_month").datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM' });
```

This is how I receive in php:

```
$year_month = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST["year_month"]);
```

Here I have to separate the year and month. How can I do that?

Comment: you want to separate year and month with JS or PHP?, show example of variable `$_REQUEST["year_month"]`

Comment: 2016-05-12 16:27:11: 2016-05. This is how I receive the year and month. Now I've to separate them. This is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try use `explode()` function:

```
<?php

$example_string = "2016-05-12 16:27:11: 2016-05";

list($year, $month) = explode("-", substr($example_string, 0, 7));

echo $year . "\n";
echo $month;
```

output:

```
2016
05
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the year and month from your datestring with the PHP [`date`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) function.

```
$dateString = "2016-05-12 16:27:11"; // = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST["year_month"]);

$year = date('Y', strtotime($dateString));
$month= date('m', strtotime($dateString));

echo "$year-$month";

>> 2016-05
```